# How to keep the plugin submenu open on viewing a custom version of users.php?

Tags: wp-admin, users, sub-menu, add-submenu-page

I have added to *my-plugin* submenu a custom view of the user list using `users.php` and a `my_plugin_view` argument to filter the request:

```
add_submenu_page(
            "my-plugin",
            'Subscribers',
            'Subscribers',
            'edit_users',
            'users.php?my_plugin_view=subscribers'
        );
```

When `/users.php?my_plugin_view=subscribers` is open the admin sidebar toggle Users > All Users instead of My Plugin > Subscribers

I have tried:

```
if( isset($_GET['my_plugin_view']) ){

    remove_submenu_page( 'users.php' );
}
```

but this removes the All Users section from the sidebar and doesn't toggle the plugin menu as expected.

How to keep the plugin submenu open on viewing a custom version of users.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a different parent slug (first parameter) to keep the user menu as you want.

An example,

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_subscriber_submenu_page');

function wpdocs_register_subscriber_submenu_page() {
      add_submenu_page(
           'users.php',
           'Subscribers',
           'Subscribers',
           'manage_options',
           'custom-submenu-page', 
           'custom_callback_function'
      );
  }
```

Try to prefix your plugin page slug, you can have conflict with such a name : 'subscribers' -> `your-plugin-subscribers` .

You will find more details [add_submenu_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. This is opening the "Users" sub-menu and I d'like to have it in the Plugin sub-menu. Am I missing something?

Comment: Basically I have the same result with your version than doing:   `add_users_page( 
   'All Subscribers', 
   'All Subscribers', 
   'administrator',
   'users.php?prefix_view=subscribers'
  );`